# Need to count number of lines from the first line of a file up to a unique character (batch)

Tags: batch-file, count

I'm new in batch. I think my question will be very simple for you. 
I need a batch script to count number of lines from the first line of a file up to a unique character "A015" which is contained into this file (this number should also be take account blank lines).
Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for /f "delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /n "A015" "file.txt"') do if not defined LineNumber set "LineNumber=%%i"
if defined LineNumber (echo "A015" found at line %LineNumber%) else echo "A015" not found
```

if there are more than one "A015" in the text file, this will show the first line number.

Comment: Running your post, i have gotten error of syntax. I have deleted the else jump and put statements following 'do' in bracket. Now sometimes echo print  "A015" found at line (does not get any number of lines). Do you see why, please? Thanks

Comment: Moreover, if I get the right line number of "A015" for the first time, then make position change into "file.txt", the line number is not updated after running script. The same value is still printed through echo. do you undestand why? thanks

Comment: from another forum, I have found this solution:                      for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "A015" ^< myfile') do (
set/a N=%%a-1
)                                                                   Now Having !N!, i'd like to go to this line number to start out my processing.
For that, i have written                                           more +!N! myfile>resultFile

no chance for me, mine doesn't work. do you have any idea of that point?
Thanks

Comment: `Need to count number of lines from the first line of a file up to a unique character` was you question and I answered it fully?

Comment: My question is answered. Thanks